# Shell em C: Erro de segmentação e função execve, o que há de errado?

Tags: c, string, shell, exec

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void type_prompt(){
    printf("\n$~");
}


void read_command(char command[], char *parameters[]){
    char linha[100] = "";
    fgets(linha, 100, stdin);

    int i;
    int flag = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <= strlen(linha); i++){
        if (linha[i] == ' '){
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    char *word = strtok(linha, " ");
    strcat(command, "/bin/");
    strcat(command, word);
    parameters[0] = word;

    if (flag == 1) command[strlen(command)] = '\0';
    else command[strlen(command) - 1] = '\0';

    if (flag == 1){
        while (word != NULL){
            word = strtok(NULL, " ");
            strcat(*parameters, word);
        }
    }
}

int main (){
    char command[] = {""};
    char *parameters[100] = {NULL}; //argv
    char *env[]={"PATH=/usr/local/sbin/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games",NULL};
    int status;

    while (1){
        type_prompt();
        read_command(command, parameters);

        if (fork() != 0){
            command[0] = '\0';
            parameters[0] = '\0';
            waitpid(-1, &status, 0);
        }

        else {  
            execve(command, parameters, env);
            command[0] = '\0';
            parameters[0] = '\0';
            printf("Erro execve %d: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Descreva melhor o seu erro e aponte exatamente o trecho do código relevante ao problema.

Comment: O objetivo do código é simular um shell. Porém, acredito que o problema está na função read_command. Pois comandos sem espaços funcionam normalmente, como o "ps", porém ao colocar "ps aux", ocorre erro de segmentação.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Há diversos erros, o problema básico é que você está manipulando o vetor parameters de forma errada, e também jogando nele trechos de string de "linha", que é uma variável que desaparece assim que a função read_command() retorna.

Segue abaixo um "diff" de linhas que alterei para fazer funcionar. O programa ainda não está perfeito, porque strdup() aloca memória na heap e a execução repetida vai vazar memória porque novos parâmetros são jogados em "parameters" sem destruir os antigos, porém ao menos o programa não quebra mais, e funciona conforme o esperado.

```
-void read_command(char command[], char *parameters[]){
-    char linha[100] = "";
+void read_command(char command[], char **parameters){
+    char linha[100];
+    linha[0] = '\0';
     fgets(linha, 100, stdin);

+    // remove o "enter"
+    linha[strlen(linha) - 1] = '\0';
+
+    printf("compr linha %d\n", strlen(linha));
+    if (strlen(linha) < 1) {
+        printf("saindo\n");
+        exit(0);
+    }
+
     int i;
     int flag = 0;
     for (i = 0; i <= strlen(linha); i++){
@@ -27,22 +37,24 @@
     char *word = strtok(linha, " ");
     strcat(command, "/bin/");
     strcat(command, word);
-    parameters[0] = word;
-
-    if (flag == 1) command[strlen(command)] = '\0';
-    else command[strlen(command) - 1] = '\0';
+    *parameters = strdup(command);
+    printf("comando: '%s'\n", command);

     if (flag == 1){
         while (word != NULL){
             word = strtok(NULL, " ");
-            strcat(*parameters, word);
+            if (word) {
+           printf("parametro: '%s'\n", word);
+                *(++parameters) = strdup(word);
+            }
         }
     }
+    *(++parameters) = NULL;
 }

 int main (){
     char command[] = {""};
-    char *parameters[100] = {NULL}; //argv
+    char *parameters[100];
     char *env[]={"PATH=/usr/local/sbin/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games",NULL};
     int status;

@@ -52,14 +64,12 @@

         if (fork() != 0){
             command[0] = '\0';
-            parameters[0] = '\0';
             waitpid(-1, &status, 0);
         }

         else {  
             execve(command, parameters, env);
             command[0] = '\0';
-            parameters[0] = '\0';
             printf("Erro execve %d: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
         }
     }
```

Comment: É exatamente isso! Obrigado, deu certo, você é incrível. Como você disse, eu não estava sabendo manipular corretamente o "parameters". Vou revisar isso, obrigado novamente pela ajuda!